# Neo4j / Cypher Query using withinDistance returns 0 rows

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spatial-query, neo4j-spatial

I've just set the Neo4j Spatial plugin on my server and I'm using SDN 3.1.2 to create my wkt index:

```
@Indexed(indexName = "CarsLocation", indexType = IndexType.POINT) var wkt: String
```

The whole works great and I can make queries involving `withinDistance` using the HTTP console like this, returning my matched node:

```
POST /db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance {"layer":"CarsLocation","pointX":48.892501,"pointY":2.373140,"distanceInKm":100.0}
```

However, I want to query using Cypher like this:

```
start n = node:CarsLocation("withinDistance:[48.892501,2.373140,100.0]") return n
```

**It just returns 0 rows, no matter the values are.**

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966722/neo4j-spatial-withindistance-cypher-query-returns-empty-while-rest-call-return) post, advising to manually add the Car node to the spatial index: CarsLocation.

So I executed this command:

```
POST /db/data/index/node/CarsLocation {"value":"dummy","key":"dummy", "uri":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/30"}  //30 being the Car node I want to index
```

but it also doesn't make the cypher query works.

I also try executing Cypher through an http call:

```
POST /db/data/cypher {"query" : "start n = node:CarsLocation({indexQuery}) return n", "params": {"indexQuery": "withinDistance:[48.892067, 2.373140, 10.0]"}}
```

Doesn't work either.

However, when I specify a huge amount of kilometers (IMO exceeding the limit), this one passes:

```
start n = node:CarsLocation("withinDistance:[48.892501,2.373140,10000.0]") return n
```

(Returning my Car node 30).

Did I miss something important?

I don't figure out where could be the mistake, preventing Cypher query to work.

I'm pointing out I'm using Neo4j 2.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mik378,

The problem here is pretty simple. The 'withinDistance' Cypher spatial index query has a quirk (a bug, as far as I'm concerned). You must specify latitude first, then longitude. I'm not familiar with SDN, so I don't know if you also need to do the explicit spatial index creation commands.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: However, I just noticed using your solution, it doesn't return all the node that should match. Using http calls, it returns 4 nodes but using cypher, only 2: `start n = node:CarsLocation("withinDistance:[2.373140, 48.892501, 100.0]") return n`

Comment: What I've just did is to clear the whole database, rename the Location in lower case, and it works with your solution :)

Comment: And clearly no need to add any indexes :) It works "out of the box"

Comment: "You must specify latitude first, then longitude" => it's the reverse actually,  48...is the latitude ;)