# Update to: Adding node to Neo4j Spatial Index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm hoping someone can provide some updated clarification on adding nodes to Spatial.  The best instructions I can find is:

[Neo4j Spatial 'WithinDistance' Cypher query returns empty while REST call returns data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966722/neo4j-spatial-withindistance-cypher-query-returns-empty-while-rest-call-return)

However it's almost 2 years old and has some contradictory information with an acknowledged bug (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/issues/106), which appears to still be open.

I also found this tutorial:

http://mattbanderson.com/setting-up-the-neo4j-spatial-extension/

Which says we should add the node to the layer AND insert the Neo4j ID# into the node as a property, but NOT insert the node to the geom index.

My main priority here is that I be able to query via Cypher (within the browser) but we will eventually want to be able to query via REST as well.  So, ideally i'd like to insert the nodes in such a way that we can do both.

So, my questions are:

1) What are the correct steps here to allow querying via both REST and Cypher?

2) If I call /addSimplePointLayer and then /index/node to add the Spatial index (both via cURL or REST), can I use LOAD CSV to insert nodes and be able to query Spatial Plugin via both REST and Cypher?

3) If I am using REST to insert my nodes, what calls (and in what order) would I need to make in order to ensure that I can query via both REST and Cypher (web browser)?

Thanks, I'm looking forward to getting this all worked out!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### question 1

You first need to initialize once a layer and create the spatial index using the REST calls:

```
POST /db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ 
    "layer" : "geom", 
    "lat" : "lat", 
    "lon" : "lon" 
}
```

and:

```
POST /db/data/index/node/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ 
    "name" : "geom", 
    "config" : { 
        "provider" : "spatial", 
        "geometry_type" : "point", 
        "lat" : "lat", 
        "lon" : "lon" 
    } 
}
```

Create a node with lon/lat properties using Cypher via the transactional endpoint:

```
POST /db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
  "statements" : [ 
  {
    "statement" : "create (city:City {data}) return id(city)",
    "parameters" : {
      "data" : {
        "name" : "MyTown",
        "lon": 15.2,
        "lat": 60.1
      }
    }
  } 
  ]
}
```

and add it to the spatial index - be sure to adopt the node id with the id of the node returned from the previous request:

```
POST /db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ 
    "layer": "geom", 
    "node": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/<my_nodeid_goes_here>" 
}
```

In order to enable Spatial play nice with Cypher a hack is required: every geo-indexed node should carry a property called `id` with the value of the node id. This can be accomplished with a simple cypher statement (the example below does this for all City nodes):

```
POST /db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ 
    "statements" : [ 
        { "statement" : "match (n:City) set n.id=id(n)" } 
    ] 
}
```

With that in place you can use Cypher for geo queries, e.g.:

```
POST /db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
  "statements" : [ 
  {
    "statement" : "start city = node:geom('withinDistance:[60.1,15.2, 100.0]') return city",
    "parameters" : {}
  } 
  ]
}
```

NB: for `withinDistance` you have to specify `lat`,`lon`, `distanceInKm`.

### question 2

As described above you need to have a separate REST call for adding a node to the spatial index. This is currently not possible with Cypher directly. As a workaround use `LOAD CSV` to create the nodes with lon/lat properties. In a preprocessing step run a statement like `MATCH (n:City) where not has(n.id) set n.id = id(n) return id(n) as id`. This will set the id properties (the hack described above) and returns a list of ids of the new nodes. For each of them emit the REST call to add a node to the geo index.

### question 3

Has been answered already above :-)

Comment: Hello Stefan, Thank you for the information and continued help and support!  You reference above "adding a node to the spatial index", but you only cite the addNodeToLayer endpoint and I don't see anywhere the /db/data/index/node/geom endpoint.  Can you please clarify?  Do I just need to add to the layer and not the spatial index?  Or the index and not the layer?  Or both?  And if both, in what order (if order matters)?

Comment: afaik `addNodeToLayer` implicitly adds it to the index as well. I've tried the described sequence of operations and the cypher query at the end returned results

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Stefan, how do you add all Nodes to the Layer?

Comment: call `/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer` for all the nodes you want to add

Comment: How can I update lat/long info of a node later, so that spatial index will remain consistent?

Comment: Also, can you explain, why I need to use `/db/data/transaction/commit` instead of `/db/data/node` in order to create a node?

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky I'm not really sure, but I assume for updating you just change the long/lat property and add that again to the spatial index using http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/#rest-api-add-a-node-to-the-spatial-index.

Comment: I've used `/db/data/transaction/commit` since I wanted to use Cypher wherever possible. You can use the `/db/data/node` endpoint as well - your choice.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happen if we accidentally added the same node to the layer that has been added previously? Will there be double nodes index now?