# How do support location based query using neo4j cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I tried to use spatial, found the official guide use legacy index in the doc, and the cypher query is not working. 
http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/#rest-api-create-a-spatial-index

How can I use latest index method '/schema/index', instead of '/index/node'?
And is there a good way to support query filter by other properties? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

cosider this hack method:
[Update to: Adding node to Neo4j Spatial Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550050/update-to-adding-node-to-neo4j-spatial-index)

the hack is :

```
POST /db/data/transaction/commit HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ 
    "statements" : [ 
        { "statement" : "match (n:City) set n.id=id(n)" } 
    ] 
}
```

then do the cypher query.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a schema index for spatial (yet).

You have to configure the spatial index either as manual or auto-index and add your nodes to it. Then the spatial cypher query works.

Comment: Can auto-index be set to be spatial index in the neo4j.properties file? it seems there's bug in the plugin. I should set the id before I can use cypher query.