# neo4j spatial: cypher returns no results

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient, neo4j-spatial

I have a database of cities with lat and long information and I am trying to get the spatial query working. Here is what I tried:

**1.Create a Layer**

```
public void CreateALayer()
{
    var restClient = new RestClient(new Uri(baseUri + "/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer"));
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddJsonBody(
        new
        {
            layer = "geom",
            lat = "lat",
            lon = "lon"
        });
    var response = restClient.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
```

**2. Assign id to neo4j's Id**
Set the id property of the city nodes to Neo4j using the following Cypher Query :

`MATCH (n:City) SET n.id = id(n)`

**3. Added the nodes to the index and layer**

```
    var nodeIds = client.Cypher.Match("(n:City)").Return(n => n.As<City>().id).Results.ToList(); ;
    foreach (var id in nodeIds)
    {
        AddNodeToIndex(id);
        AddNodeToLayer(id);
    }
```

//

```
public void AddNodeToIndex( long nodeId)
    {
        string URINode = string.Format("{0}/db/data/node/{1}", baseUri, nodeId);
        //# Create geom index
        var restClient = new RestClient(new Uri(baseUri + "/db/data/index/node/" + indexName));
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddJsonBody(
            new
            {
                value = "dummy",
                key = "dummy",
                uri = URINode
            });
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
         Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```

//

```
public void AddNodeToLayer(long nodeId)
    {
        string URINode = string.Format("{0}/db/data/node/{1}", baseUri, nodeId);
        string URIAdd = string.Format("{0}/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer", baseUri);

        /*string json = string.Format("{{\"layer\":\"{0}\", \"node\":\"{1}\"}}", layer, URINode);
        HTTPCommand(new Uri(URIAdd), json);*/

        var restClient = new RestClient(new Uri(URIAdd));
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddJsonBody(
            new
            {
                layer = indexName,
                node = URINode
            });
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```

I can see that the nods are getting created , but not sure if that is correct though:
[image]

I am trying to run the following query and it keeps returning me no rows.
`START n=node:geom('withinDistance:[27.97,77.58, 10000000]') RETURN n`

[image]

Can some one please point me what I may be missing here.

**EDIT 1:**
I see that when I post the following message

`:POST /db/data/index/node {"name":"geom", "config":{"provider":"spatial", "geometry_type":"point","lat":"lat","lon":"lon"}}`

I get this error in the logs:

```
2015-12-18 04:44:38.094+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.KernelHealth]: setting TM not OK. Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform necessary action (tx recovery/restart)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.SpatialIndexImplementation.newApplier(Z)Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/transaction/command/NeoCommandHandler;
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LegacyIndexApplierLookup$Direct.newApplier(LegacyIndexApplierLookup.java:48) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LegacyIndexApplier.applier(LegacyIndexApplier.java:91) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LegacyIndexApplier.visitIndexCreateCommand(LegacyIndexApplier.java:163) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.CommandApplierFacade.visitIndexCreateCommand(CommandApplierFacade.java:274) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexCommand$CreateCommand.handle(IndexCommand.java:314) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.CommandApplierFacade.visit(CommandApplierFacade.java:82) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.CommandApplierFacade.visit(CommandApplierFacade.java:45) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.PhysicalTransactionRepresentation.accept(PhysicalTransactionRepresentation.java:69) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionRepresentationStoreApplier.apply(TransactionRepresentationStoreApplier.java:108) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.applyToStore(TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.java:107) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.commit(TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.java:64) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.commit(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:502) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.close(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:418) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.LegacyIndexStore.getOrCreateIndexConfig(LegacyIndexStore.java:201) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.LegacyIndexStore.getOrCreateNodeIndexConfig(LegacyIndexStore.java:63) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeLegacyIndexCreateLazily(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:1318) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeLegacyIndexCreateLazily(OperationsFacade.java:820) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexProviderImpl.getOrCreateNodeIndex(IndexProviderImpl.java:51) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:81) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.createNodeIndex(DatabaseActions.java:391) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.jsonCreateNodeIndex(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:834) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_72]
```

As I am not a Java expert, I am not curious to know if I missed any package here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the node to both the layer and the index. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25446475/2954199 for a detailed explanation, but it appears that if you add the node to both the layer and the index then the IndexProvider used by the Cypher call will not return the nodes correctly.

So try only adding the nodes to the index (using the `/db/data/index/node/geom` REST call) and not `/addNodeToLayer` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either. However in the link you provided I see that I need to POST the following `:POST /db/data/index/node/ {"name":"geom", "config":{"provider":"spatial", "geometry_type":"point","lat":"lat","lon":"lon"}}` however this gives me `Error: 500 - Server Error` and the neo4j stops more or less and I can't connect to it any more. any ideas what mey be the issue

Comment: I see the error log that says I ma missing something here, I have updated my original message. Can you please help me understand what I missed